# Adding Tabs to Google Sheets Based on Form Response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to conceptualize my structure and values needed to organize form responses in multiple sheets within a Google Sheet based on the value selected for one of my form question responses ("Location of Change"). I have a checklist that is completed so far as below. I also listed the additional steps and what I think I need to create to achieve what I'm looking for. Can someone guide me in pointing out where I might have issues or a better approach?

1. Open Form - Completed
2. Open Spreadsheet - Completed
3. Form saves responses in proper format to Spreadsheet - Completed
4. Set form responses to a variable - Completed
5. Set form questions to a variable - Completed
6. Find "Location of Change" Questions in a for loop - Completed
7. Get Responses and group response within new tabs in Google Sheets based on value for "Location of Change"

To work on step 7, my original thought is to create a for loop within my for loop based on the form response and then within that for loop create an if/else statement to create a new tab if it doesn't exist and save values to that sheet, otherwise just add values to appropriate tab name.

Does this sound right? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

**UPDATE:**

```
function onSubmit() {

  //Open Marketing - Discoveries and Changes - v1
  var form = FormApp.openById('id');

  //Open Marketing - Discoveries and Changes - v1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');

  //Capture Form Responses
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();

  //Capture Questions 
  var items = form.getItems();

  for (var i in items) {

    var title = items[7].getTitle();
    Logger.log(title);

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you narrow down this set of concepts a bit? The first 6 steps that you've completed could be done in many ways, which affects evaluation of your proposed next step. Adding some code that clarifies what your existing "for loop" is would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Mogsdad thanks for your response and I updated my question to include the code I have so far. Hope this helps a bit

Comment: Thanks for doing that edit - it helps immensely! (You probably want `items[i]`, not `items[7]`, by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general thought process is fine, but you are making inappropriate choices for the specific objects and methods that you're using to address the problem.

You've started by naming your function `onSubmit()`, which implies that it is some type of Form Submission trigger function. As long as you're intending to process form responses as they arrive, this is the right approach. There are two flavours of these trigger functions, and it's not clear which you intend this to be, so you need to make a decision there.

#### Use properties of the Event object

Trigger functions respond to events, and when they are invoked trigger functions are given an [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that includes the most relevant information about the event.

Your function isn't currently using the Event object, but it should, with an immediate benefit: In your initial script you are hard-coding the IDs for the Form and Spreadsheet, but you don't need to.

Depending on the type of Form Submission trigger function this is, you can modify the preamble to take advantage of the linkage between forms and spreadsheets, using the [event data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) that is passed to the trigger function when it is invoked. (This assumes that you have linked a spreadsheet with your form - for your application this may not be required.)

If your script is a **Google Forms** Form Submit Submit Event with an Event parameter `e`:

```js
var form = e.source;
var ssId = form.getDestinationId();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
```

If your script is a **Google Sheets** Form Submit Event with an Event parameter `e`:

```js
var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
var ss = sheet.getParent();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());
```

Using either of those approaches will produce more portable code, since they adapt to the context of the event being handled.

But that's not all... the responses that you're opening the form for are provided as properties on the Event object as well! Because of that, you may find that you don't need to go opening the form at all.

#### Storing responses in specific sheets according to input data

> To work on step 7, my original thought is to create a for loop within my for loop based on the form response and then within that for loop create an if/else statement to create a new tab if it doesn't exist and save values to that sheet, otherwise just add values to appropriate tab name.

The language here is a bit confusing, but here's what I understand it to mean: *Select a target sheet within the destination spreadsheet and append the new responses, depending on what the response to "Location of Change" is.* Don't worry about the details of looping etc. just yet.

From what we've already seen about Event objects, all the info you need to operate is available to you. For example, in a **Google Sheets** Form Submission trigger function you could do this:

```js
// Choose destination sheet according to Location of Change
var destSheet = getSheet(ss, e.namedValues['Location of Change']);
// Store the current response in destination sheet
destSheet.appendRow(e.values);
```

That is simplified by use of a utility function, `getSheet()`.

#### Get or create a sheet

This utility function encapsulates the logic to either get a reference to an existing sheet with a given name, or create one if necessary.

```js
/**
 * Get the sheet with given name. Create sheet if it doesn't exist.
 * New sheet will be created with optional headings, if provided.
 *
 * From: 
 *
 * @param {Spreadsheet} spreadsheet   Google Spreadsheet object.
 * @param {String}      sheetName     Sheet name to get.
 * @param {String[]}    headings      Optional array of headings (for new sheet).
 *
 * @returns {Sheet}                   Sheet object.
 */
function getSheet( spreadsheet, sheetName, headings ) {
  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (sheet == null) {
    // Not found, so add new sheet
    sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
    if (headings && headings.constructor === Array) {
      sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headings.length).setValues([headings]);
    }
  }

  return sheet;
}
```

#### Sheets Alternative

You could accomplish almost all this without a script, just using features of Google Sheets.

- Start with your current form, with a Spreadsheet response destination.
- In the spreadsheet, form response will typically go to a sheet named "Form Responses", perhaps with a number after it.
- Insert additional sheets for the categories you're interested in. In each of these, use a spreadsheet QUERY function to select the sub-set of responses that are relevant. This is simplified if you use a common cell, A1 say, to store the category, then put the QUERY function in a subsequent row, referring to the value in A1. That way, additional sheets can be copied from this one, and adjusted by modifying just the content of A1.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful!

Comment: quick questions. There is an error at line ` var sheet = e.range.getSheet(); ` with your code. The error says `TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "")` It seems like this is due to not knowing what Google Sheet file to access. Am I correct with my assumption?

Comment: @cphill Nope. It's because `e` isn't defined when you're running in the debugger. See [How to test a trigger function in GAS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067)

Comment: I see, so based on the examples from the question you linked, I need to remove the `e` parameter from the function, define the Google Sheets in the standard format, create a for loop and define `e` and my onSubmit functionality within that for loop. Does this sound right? I also tried without running the debugger by publishing "test as an add on"  and the functionality did not work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read that over a couple of times and I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The name of your function, `onSubmit()`, _implies_ that it is a trigger function. (It would still need to be [installed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to catch form responses as they arrive.) You can _call_ `onSubmit()` from a test function with a _simulated_ event. You don't need to dissect it to do so.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I created a trigger, onSubmit - Events - From Spreadsheet - On form submit, which would match my `onSubmit(e)` function. The issue is that when I run a test through `test as add-on` I receive an error from the `onSubmit` function with the message `No item with given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it.` it points to line 9, which is  ` var form = FormApp.openById(ss.getFormUrl());` Does this mean I need to attach the forms url?

Comment: It means either there is no form attached to the spreadsheet, or there is but the document user isn't authorized to open the form. (When using "test as add-on", you have some control over who the test will emulate.) I suggest asking a new question rather than continuing this in comments.

Comment: I think this is where I might be running into the issue. Will do